# Access data source thru Power BI gateway

Tags: rest, api, push, powerbi, gateway

We have a need of accessing a data source from Power BI service using the push data set mechanism.

As the data source resides on a private network, the idea is to set up a Power BI gateway providing us direct access without opening up the network firewall.

Now, we see that the PBI gateway offers a variety of connection options, e.g. Oracle, MS SQLServer, DB2 etc - but our data source primarily offers a Rest API.

Is it possible to connect to this data source directly thru the PBI gateway? We can't find this example anywhere in the documentation or on the web (and assuming that it will be a common use case since most systems nowadays don't expose their DB directly).

Comment: Use Odata connection